Upgrade from PostgreSQL 11 to 14 in RHEL dependency errors
I use RHEL 7.5 to host postgresql11 and I want to upgrade the existing postgresql to 14.
I initialized the DB and proceeded to check the upgrade.
While using the pg_upgrade --check it tells me that pg_trgm is missing along with tablefunc and postgres_fdw.
Ok so I google that, it seems that postgresql14-contrib needs to be installed. When I try to install postgresql14-contrib I get the error that it requires libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit). So it seems that nothing in my repolist provides this and I downloaded the .rpm manually to install it but then I get more dependency problems that yum is unable to resolve. Is there a way to point yum to find all the dependencies it needs?
NOTE:The VM that runs RHEL 7.5 is behind a firewall
I tried copying the pg_trgm.so,tablefunc.so and postgres_fdw.so from the older version as a workaround but I get errors when I run the pg_upgrade --check.
I also tried using yum search python3. It returned a lot of results but I am not sure which version to install.
Thanks for your time reading this and I am sorry if the answer is right in my face but its the first time that I am dealing with RHEL and yum, and I already spent about 10 hours trying to solve this by myself.

"The VM that runs RHEL 7.5 is behind a firewall" Get a machine that is not behind a firewall and install it there. then you know what you need, and you can download those packages. There is no better way.

That isn't possible @Laurenz. Even if I did that locally with internet access how will I know what to allow through firewall?

You download the packages on the machine with internet access (dnf download --resolve <package>) and put them on a USB stick or similar.

Ok I spinned up a VM on my PC with RHEL server 7.5 with internet access and it still can resolve the libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) dependency. I tried installing EPEL for this version and still it doesn't find it anywhere. Any thoughts?

It may well be that you need to update RHEL to 7.latest. I don't know if that resolves your problem, but it may.

You can also run pg_upgrade in docker, check this project
